# Reset scroll in ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a ScrollView (and a LinearLayout within it) set as main content. When the user scrolls the view further down, and then if I replace it's child (LinearLayout) with another LinearLayout, the view remains in the scrolled positioned.

How do I reset the ScrollView back to coordinate 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its all in the documentation... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html search for `fullScroll(int)`

Answer (score 27):

Why not just use `scrollTo(0, 0);`?

Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollTo(int%2C%20int)

Comment: I noticed that scrollTo(0,0) works better. smoothScrollTo and fullScroll sometimes just don't really go to the top. I don't know why. I think it has something to do with the scrolling animation. scrollTo just 'jumps' to the top and that is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what fitted in my use case. I wanted to scroll with animation. It works like charm. But I guess someone who wants to scroll with animation should go with scrollview.fullScroll(scrollVIew.FOCUS_TOP)

Answer (score 4):

If u want to clear the scrollview u can use
removeAllViews();

Answer (score 1):

When **scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0)** & ***scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP)*** doesn't work, you can accomplish the intended with:

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

yourScrollView.scrollTo(0,0) will do the job just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
ScrollView hscrollViewMain = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollViewMain);
hscrollViewMain.scrollTo(0, 0);
```